# Is there a way to work with Visual Studio 2010 solutions using 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2017

I would like to rid my machine of all old versions of Visual Studio and just use 2017.  However, I need to work with Visual Studio 2010 solutions without upgrading them (they must continue to work for developers using 2010).  Is there any way I can set up my 2017 to do that?

Answer (score 2):

This MSDN article: [Port, Migrate, and Upgrade Visual Studio Projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/porting/port-migrate-and-upgrade-visual-studio-projects) says that it depends on the type of project you are opening. If its a Windows Presentation Foundation project in Visual Studio 2010 SP1 you are in luck. If it's a C++ project then the oldest project VS 2017 will open without converting is from 2015.

I have maintained old Visual Studio projects with newer versions of Visual Studio before. In doing so I have run into headaches with VS silently updating resource files to new formats and there being minor discrepancies between the toolset versions. I keep multiple versions of Visual Studio installed and open the projects with the version that matches. It's not an elegant solution but it means I spend more time fixing bugs and less time hunting down migration issues in project files.

Comment: I thought one of the selling points of 2017 was that you could open old solutions without converting them.

Answer (score -2):

In Visual Studio, on the File menu, click Open and then click Project/Solution, Web Site, or File, depending on the kind of project you are upgrading.
In the Open Project dialog box, select a project file, and then click Open.
If Visual Studio detects that the project or file was created in an earlier version of Visual Studio, the Visual Studio Conversion Wizard opens.
Complete the Visual Studio Conversion Wizard

And also try .sln file open with .txt and chenge version try it